# get list of files of a folder on server with json in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

i'm using these code to get list of files of a folder on server :

```
<?php
 if ($handle = opendir('.pic')) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            //$thelist = $thelist.$file.'<br>';
            $thelist = $thelist.$file."\r\n";
          }
       }
  closedir($handle);
  }
 echo $thelist;
?>
```

it is work fine, but i need to get files name with json array, for mysql i'm using these codes to get json array:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM wall ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response["products"] = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $product = array();
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    $response["success"] = 1;
echo json_encode($response);
```

but i don't know how to change it to get files name with json array just like mysql.

**UPDATE :**
i try these codes :

```
<?php
 $thelist = array();
 if ($handle = opendir('.pic')) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $thelist[] = $file;
          }
       }
  closedir($handle);
  }
 echo json_encode($thelist);
```

and in android i try to get json with these code :

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url_all_products, params);
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());
```

and i have this eror in logcat :

Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

so can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using `glob()` to get list of files (and/or folders) from folders in general.

First of all, you should initialize an array and then later append to that array.

**Here is my solution:**

```
<?php
$list = []; // Since 5.4.x you can use shorthand syntax to init an array
$dir = dirname(__FILE__); // Just to get the path to current dir

// glob returns an array with the files it found matching the search pattern (* = wildcard)
$files = glob($dir."/.pic/*");

// Looping through all the files found in ./.pic
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // Removing the full path and appending the file to the $list array.
    // Now it will look like ".pic/filename.ext"
    $list[] = str_replace($dir."/", "", $file); 
}
echo json_encode($list, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); // JSON_PRETTY_PRINT for beautifying the output
?>
```

On a sidenote, `glob()` can take more options, you can read more about it in  the [php manual (glob)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

**Suggestion to update nr 1**
The output of this json will be a json array, as the error message said it found. A solution can be to change `JSONObject json` to `JSONArray json`.

On the other hand, you can make the output of the PHP script to be a json object instead of array by doing a small little tweak in the code.

Instead of `echo json_encode($list, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`, simply add the `$list` to another array like this:
`echo json_encode(['files' => $list], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

This will make the parser see it as a json object because the array has a string key (`files`) instead of a index key (`0, 1, ..., n`)

Answer (score 0):

Make an array of filenames, and json_encode that:

```
<?php
 $thelist = array();
 if ($handle = opendir('.pic')) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            $thelist[] = $file;
          }
       }
  closedir($handle);
  }
 echo json_encode($thelist);
```